# Flushing within twocolumn article

Tags: horizontal-alignment, two-column

I am new to LaTeX and I'm creating a template for handins for school work.
I am using the `article` document class with the `twoclumn` option. In the beginning of the template I am making a header with name of class and title for
exercise. I would like to be able to, on a line in the header, write something at the beginning of the line and then on the same line flush something to the right margin but in the first column. Sketch:

`MyClassTitle ___________space_____________ SomethingHere  || Right column`

where `||` denotes the boundary between the two columns. I have been trying with flushright and raggedleft but can not make it work.

Answer (score 4):

Is this what you're after:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}% http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum
\begin{document}
{\large \textbf{MyClassTitle} \hfill \textit{SomethingHere}}

\lipsum[1-10]
\end{document}
```

[image: Title/header in two-column article]

In the above code the [`lipsum` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum) is used merely to fill the document with dummy text. Also, you'll notice that the title (just like all the other paragraphs) have an indent. If you want to remove this indent, add `\noindent` on the same line just before the heading. I've formatted the heading using `\large` (to increase the font size), `\textbf` (for **bold face** font), and `\textit` (for *italics* font).